# Error while creating sync folder via Vagrant in Ubuntu (VirtualBox)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I get the following error:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. 
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
mkdir -p /home/myuser/synced
```

Host: Windows 10
Guest: Ubuntu Server 17.10

My Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "mybox"

  config.ssh.shell = "bash -l"
  config.ssh.username = "myuser"
  config.ssh.password = "mypassword"  

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/home/myuser/synced", create: true, group: "mygroup", owner: "myuser"

end
```

When logged in via SSH into guest I can invoke

```
mkdir -p /home/myuser/synced
```

without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by the lack of the passwordless sudo in my custom basebox.

How to setup passwordless sudo: https://serverfault.com/a/596988

Please remember to use:

```
sudo visudo
```

for editing sudoers file.

And more info on the subject: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos